# Want to perform Website tracking (only Website visits) through Collect tracking code

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, einstein-recommendations

Client wants to track known visitors on there website and they are not into e-commerce business.
so we have updated content catalog in email recommendation section and this account doesn't has Web recommendation in place.

1. Can we achieve website tracking through email recommendation option. and business don't want to recommend any product or content. Just want to have website visitors data in IGO DE's.
2. Content catalog consist of ContentID, Link, Availability, Title.
   -> We have updated dummy ContentID, Link has Website URL, Availability has Y, and Title has Website title.
3. Collect code which we have updated on website is below. we have replaced MID with account id.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//MID.collect.igodigital.com/collect.js"></script>
<script> 
var_etmc = [];
_etmc.push(["setOrgId", "MID"]);
_etmc.push(["trackPageView"]); </script
script>
_etmc.push(["setOrgId", "MID"]);
_etmc.push(["trackPageView, {"Item" : ContentID, "Link" : Link, "Title":Title]); 
</script>
```

but still we are not seeing any data coming into IGO DE's apart from PI_CONTENT and PI_CONTENTATTRIBS.

We what to track known users with there email id and which page subscriber has visited and time stamp.

Could anyone please provide answers, or guide us in implementing the collect tracking code.

Comment: so the only other DE you would populate with the above implementation would be pi_contentviews if the item tracked is in the catalog

Comment: Thanks @EazyE, 
Could you please guide us how to populate data into IGO DE's, or how to track email id of subscriber, which page subscriber has visited and the time stamp. That will be the great help. Thanks.

Comment: you need to setuserinfo in the collect code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The catalogue data extensions (PI_CONTENT and PI_CONTENTATTRIBS) are not dependent on the behaviour tracking, as the data is originating from the uploaded catalogue.

When trying to enable data extension integration in Einstein Web Recommendations, you might see some notifications explaining why your data is not coming into your data extensions. In my case, when a brand new catalogue is uploaded (with no other activities done), I am seeing these issues:

- This feature requires existing Einstein data extensions. Confirmation is pending, check back shortly. Contact support if you continue to see this message.
- This feature requires a catalog. Please ensure you've uploaded a catalog.
- This feature requires completion of the first time user experience. Please ensure that data collection has been set up and a recommendation page has been created.
- No item detail views have been collected in the last 24 hours. The igo_views data extension will not populate until item detail views are collected.
- No conversions have been collected in the last 24 hours. The igo_purchases data extension will not populate until conversions are collected.

Please have a look at especially number 3 item. Even though you don't need recommendations, you still need to configure at least one recommendation page, for the data to flow into the data extensions.

And also, as EazyE is telling you - setUserInfo also needs to be included in the code, for IGO_PROFILES to be populated with the value from setUserInfo, mapping it to the internal GUID of Einstein Recommendations.